# Converting from X,Y,Z offset representing a rotation to matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been working on figuring out 3-dimensional rotations for graphics and I've reached a brick wall of understanding that I can't power through.

Right now I have a function which calculates the X,Y,Z offsets of a point. With the timing I have in place I have these offsets being calcuted:

(X = X offset, Y = y offset, Z = z offset)

0  seconds --> X = 5,  Y = -3.5, Z = -20

3  seconds --> X = 0,  Y = -3.5, Z = -15

6  seconds --> X = -5, Y = -3.5, Z = -20

9  seconds --> X = 0,  Y = -3.5, Z = -25

12 seconds --> X = 5,  Y = -3.5, Z = -20

I see how I could model my angle as a map from 0 to 12 TO 0 to 2*PI. However, doing this directly using the normal Y rotation scheme would result in a rotation over the origin. Also, I don't see how to reconcile the rotation's radius being 5.

With the offsets, the point (1,1,1) would go to (1, -2.5, -14) at 3 seconds.

My first thought was direct rotation. The point (1,1,1) would then go to (1,1,-1). This is wrong since it doesn't take into account the shifting of positions. If I directly add my intended position at 0, given by (1+5 = 6,1 - 3.5 = -2.5, 1 - 20 = -19), to the result I'd get (7,-2.5,-20). This doesn't work.

My next idea was to first move the point to it's location given at time = 0. Then I would bias this value with the spot I'm rotating around. I can't figure this out but I know it's related to my offsets. Then I'd perform the rotation around the y axis and finally translate back using the bias.

Is the layout in the last paragraph correct? I'm getting the impression I'm doing too much translating. Also, how would I go about figuring out my bias if it is correct? If it's not the right layout, how should I approach this problem?

I'd appreciate any help, thanks in advance.